# Library for visualizing users on map over time

Tags: javascript, dictionary, visualization

I have data corresponding to user events with (location, time). I would like to visualize these on an animated map. Maybe with points of light appearing when an event happens (with multiple events in the same place making a brighter dot). Double points for animating the day/night regions on the map at the same time. Is there a javascript library good for visualizing such data?

The map on the right side of [this visualization](http://max-planck-research-networks.net/) written in processing doesn't quite fit my description, but would also work well.

Answer (score 4):

I found that [d3.js](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/) worked really well for the project. The geo module made it easy to draw a world map (with data from data/world-countries.json and a mercator projection) in an svg element. First, I pre-processed the data to put the users in "buckets" of gps locations.  I added a circle for every location, and changed its radius for how many users were in that bucket.

Comment: I'd love to see how that came out, can you share?